# Deploy node js code with python script running through child_process

Tags: python, node.js

I have a code that is in node js and using child_process invoking the python code to do some functions. The code I'm deploying to azure app service. Everything was working fine in local but when deploying the python code is not working. Can anyone give me some guidance to make the python code work in the node js code in azure app service.

Comment: `the python code is not working` That means what?!

Comment: I mean Python code is not executing

Comment: Is python installed, what version, what error message do you get?! Post some logs, debug messages, etc. Should i ask ma magic 8 ball whats wrong or how do you expect any help?

Comment: Yes python is installed and when I tried with a simple code that does not need any packages its working. Is there a way I can install python packages in app service. I tried installing from KUDU console and it tells 

Requirement already satisfied: cryptography in c:\home\python364x64\lib\site-packages (37.0.0)